# Files not getting creating in Unity MAC build

Tags: c#, macos, file, unity-game-engine

I have the following piece of code which is creating a text file in Windows build game, but the same is not creating any files in a Mac build game. I do not have a Mac to debug the code, but I can play the game on an external public Mac computer. I tried using `Application.dataPath` as well, but the file is not getting created anyway in a MacOS

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;

/// <summary>
/// This class serves as the single interface for all file writing.
/// The idea is to report all important events so that the game's
/// actions can be coded and compared to viewed reactions from video.
/// </summary>
public static class FileManagement
{
    private static bool wasInit = false;
    private static string FILENAME;
    private static string DUMPNAME;

    // Get the date to use as the file name.
    public static void init()
    {
        wasInit = true;
        // To ensure files are not overwritten and are easily identifiable, we will name them with the current date and time.
        int day = DateTime.Now.Day;
        int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
        int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        int minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        int second = DateTime.Now.Second;
        FILENAME = (GameInfo.gameTitle + "-" + month + "-" + day + "-" + year + "-" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second);
        // The dump file holds all the emotion measurements for each frame. Put in a separate file to not clog other data.
        DUMPNAME = FILENAME + "-ENGAGEMENT-DUMP.txt";
        FILENAME += ".txt";
    }


    // Helper to get timestamp string.
    private static string getTime()
    {
        return "[" + Time.time + "] ";
    }

    // Helper to open and write to the file. Keeping all the possible errors to one point.
    private static void print(string message)
    {
        if (!wasInit)
        {
            init();
        }

        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(FILENAME, true))
        {
            // The using command here automatically closes and flushes the file.
            file.WriteLine(getTime() + message);
        }

    }

    // Public version to accept any sort of message.
    public static void printToFile(string message)
    {
        print(message);
    }
}
```

This is my folder structure for the mac and pc builds>>
[image]

Comment: Using `Application.persistentDataPath` instead fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with using file write permission in Mac. Writing the files inside the folder goverened by `Application.persistentDataPath` fixed the issue.